# Unable to uncheck checkbox with jquery in wp admin

Tags: jquery, wp-admin

My js code:

```
$('div[aria-label="Asukohad"] input[type="checkbox"]').on("change", function() {
    var element = $(this);

    if(element.is(":checked")) {
        //todo
    } else {
        uncheckAll();
    }
});

function uncheckAll() {
    $('div[aria-label="Asukohad"] input[type="checkbox"]').attr('checked', false);
}
```

When I select some checkboxes and then unselect one of them, all the checkboxes get unchecked, which is great. But now when I select another checbox all the other checkboxes are also getting checked which where unchekced by jQuery. I got a feeling that I have to sync the checkboxes somehow when I do the unchecking with jQuery.

Checkboxes are located in post/page properties panel.

Video demo:https://vimeo.com/343601969

Answer (score 1):

Can you please clarify your question? Are you attempting to make a checkbox that can clear all checkboxes and also recheck all checkboxes by checking that one checkbox?

Also a checked input would be written like this:

```
<input id="editor-post-taxonomies-hierarchical-term-48" class="editor-post-taxonomies__hierarchical-terms-input" type="checkbox" checked value="48" />
```

You can do this:

```
$('div[aria-label="Asukohad"] input[type="checkbox"]').on("change", function() {
var element = $(this);

if(element.is(":checked")) {
    // do nothing.
} else {
    uncheckAll();
}
});

function uncheckAll() {
    $('div[aria-label="Asukohad"] input[type="checkbox"]').removeProp('checked');
}
```

Comment: No, Im trying to make a checkbox that can clear all checkboxes. When rechecking only the current checkbox should get checked, not the ones that were unchecked with jQuery. My checked input does not look like you showed. Maybe thats relatead with this wierd behavior.

Comment: your video is not working, can you give an explanation of the difference between checkboxes that were unchecked and what is meant by current?

Comment: I updated the video link. https://vimeo.com/343601969. Video shows what is happening now. By current I mean that the checkbox I click should only get clicked. Not the ones which were unchecked previously by jquery.

Comment: I updated my answer with something that should work for what you seem to be wanting it to do. Please mark as answer if it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question, so here you go.

To check all boxes:

```
jQuery('#select-button').on('click',function(){
    jQuery('.outer-div td label input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true);
});
```

To uncheck all boxes:

```
jQuery('#select-button').on('click',function(){
    jQuery('.outer-div td label input[type="checkbox"]').removeProp('checked');
});
```